# Applying the weierstrass criterion to a power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I want to show that for all $\delta > 0$, the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges uniformly on the set $S:=\{z \in \mathbb C \mid |z-1|\geq \delta,|z|\leq1\}$ if $a_n$ is a monotonically decreasing series of positive, real numbers (edit: and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$).

My idea was to apply the weierstrass criterion: If I can show $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \lVert a_n z^n \rVert_\infty < \infty$, the power series converges uniformly (right?).

But when I try to prove it, I end up with $\lVert a_n z^n \rVert_\infty = a_n$,

$$\lVert a_n z^n \rVert_\infty=\sup_{z \in S} |a_n z^n|=a_n \sup_{z \in S} |z|^n=a_n$$

and that doesn't imply $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \lVert a_n z^n \rVert_\infty < \infty$ because e.g. $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \frac 1n = \infty$.

Is my attempt correct? Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Suppose that $(\forall n\in\mathbb Z_+):a_n=1$. Then your series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$, which diverges when $\lvert z\rvert=1$. Or, if you dislike the fact that this sequence is constant, take $a_n=1+\frac1{n+1}$.

However, the statement is true if you add the hypothesis that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Then it follows from [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel%27s_uniform_convergence_test).

Comment: Yes, sorry - i forgot that point. Thank you. I already proved that $(1-z)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges. But I don't get the point in the proof after the equation. Why does $a_n z^{n+1}$ converges *uniformly* to zero when $(a_n)_n$ converges to zero? And why is it then enough to show that $\sum_{n=1}^n (a_k - a_{k-1}) z^k$ converges?

Comment: If you add the hypohesis that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ is uniformly bounded on $S$ and the series of (constant) functions $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$ is monotonic and converge uniformly to the null function. Therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ converges uniformly on $S$; that's what the test says.

Comment: Do you tink that there is something missing from my answer?

Comment: I thought about it a while and now I get the proof on the wikipedia site - it's only a proof for convergence, not for uniform convergence. But how does the uniform convergence follows from Abel's test? Because that is exactly what I want to prove in this case. Isn't my attempt working? Because then I could easily reference to the weierstrass criterion... but if I didn't made a mistake, the attempt is obviously not working...

Comment: [The link that I provided above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel%27s_uniform_convergence_test) is for Abel's test for **uniform** convergence. I don't think that you can solve your problem using the Weierstrass test.